# orderBy not working as expected: Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-orderby

My array is : `BS`. Its structure is :

```
Array[317]
0: Object
   $$hashKey: "022"
   name: "Los Angeles Comm."
.
.
.
..
```

BS is an array. Each value is a JSon object with filed of name.

I want to sort all the values of BS according to their name. I am trying :

```
<option ng-repeat="item in BS | orderBy:item.name"  value="{{item.name}}">{{item.name}}</option>
```

I have also tried : `orderBy:name` and `orderBy:item[name]`. Nothing works. Why is this not working and whats the correct code?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Have a look at below html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="item">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="item in items|orderBy:'name'">
                {{item.name}}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script>
        var AppModule = angular.module('app', []);
        function item($scope) {
            $scope.items = [{ name: 'tur' }, { name: 'abc' }, { name: 'xyx' }];

        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: One thing to note here is that if you use the `track by ---` syntax, your orderBy will no longer work.

Comment: @dmackerman, `track by ---` must always be at the very end of the entire expression, including to the right of filters. Then `orderBy` works as expected.

Comment: @nilskp, is there any documentation that tells why `track by` must be at the end? I'm wondering why `track by` is allowed anywhere else other than at the end if it causes undesired behavior.

Comment: Darn didnt know you needed to wrap in apostrophe's! Thank you.